# Why liquibase unable to resolved the db.changelog classpath?

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot, liquibase

Here is the structure, one of the maven dependency jar project, which one contains **liquibase** change logs in **classpath** as following:

```
chorke─init─change-1.0.00.GA.jar!
 └─ META-INF/
    └─ migrations/
        ├─ db.changelog-master.xml
        ├─ config/
        │   ├─ db.changelog-config.xml
        │   ├─ db.changelog-property.xml
        │   └─ db.changelog-restrict.xml
        └─ change/
            ├─ db.changelog-1.xml
            ├─ db.changelog-2.xml
            ├─ V1/
            │   ├─ db.changelog-1.0.xml
            │   ├─ db.changelog-1.1.xml
            │   ├─ V1.0/
            │   │   ├─ db.changelog-1.0.00.xml
            │   │   ├─ db.changelog-1.0.01.xml
            │   │   ├─ V1.0.00/
            │   │   │   ├─ db.changelog-1.0.00.000.xml
            │   │   │   ├─ db.changelog-1.0.00.001.xml
            │   │   │   ├─ db.changelog-1.0.00.002.xml
            │   │   │   └─ db.changelog-1.0.00.999.xml
            │   │   └─ V1.0.01/
            │   │       ├─ db.changelog-1.0.01.000.xml
            │   │       ├─ db.changelog-1.0.01.001.xml
            │   │       ├─ db.changelog-1.0.01.002.xml
            │   │       └─ db.changelog-1.0.01.999.xml
            │   └─ V1.1/
            │       ├─ db.changelog-1.1.00.xml
            │       ├─ db.changelog-1.1.01.xml
            │       ├─ V1.1.00/db.changelog-1.1.00.###.xml
            │       └─ V1.1.01/db.changelog-1.1.01.###.xml
            └─ V2/
                ├─ db.changelog-2.#.xml
                └─ V2.#/V2.#.##/db.changelog-2.#.##.###.xml
```

Here is **db.changelog-master.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd
    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">

    <includeAll path="config" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
    <include file="change/db.changelog-1.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
    <include file="change/db.changelog-2.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Which one loaded by **spring-boot** `application.properties`as following

```
liquibase.change-log=classpath:/META-INF/migrations/db.changelog-master.xml
```

Executed well when it's in the same project. On dependent project it executed as following:

1. ***DATABASECHANGELOG*** table created
2. ***DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK*** table created
3. *But no **update migration** performed!*

When **db.changelog-master.xml** loaded by **liquibase maven plugin** as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <!-- intentionally configuration skipped -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.chorke.init</groupId>
            <artifactId>chorke-init-change</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.00.GA</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <propertyFileWillOverride>true</propertyFileWillOverride>
                    <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
                    <changeLogFile>classpath:/META-INF/migrations/db.changelog-master.xml</changeLogFile>
                    <propertyFile>${project.build.directory}/test-classes/liquibase-update.properties</propertyFile>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>update</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
                        <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
                        <version>1.14</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Error with the message:

```
Failed to execute goal
org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.5.3:update (default) on project
chorke-init-migrat: Error setting up or running Liquibase:
classpath:/META-INF/migrations/db.changelog-master.xml does not exist
```

In this situation your guideline expected for error free **liquibase migration** for the dependent project those are using **spring-boot** or **liquibase-maven-plugin**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The structure mentioned for `chorke─init─change-1.0.00.GA.jar` contains **liquibase change logs** in **classpath** is good enough and **spring-boot** `application.properties` also configured exactly. But there were some silly mistake in **liquibase-maven-plugin** configuration, It should be corrected as following:

```
<configuration>
    <propertyFileWillOverride>true</propertyFileWillOverride>
    <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
    <changeLogFile>META-INF/migrations/db.changelog-master.xml</changeLogFile>
    <propertyFile>liquibase-update.properties</propertyFile>
</configuration>
```

There were two mistakes in **liquibase-maven-plugin** configuration those are:

1. First one for `changeLogFile`
2. Second one for `propertyFile`

No need to use prefix like `classpath:` or `classpath:/` for `changeLogFile`, Also need not to use absolute or relative path like `${project.build.directory}/test-classes/` for `propertyFile`. Leave it simple. It's the own business of **liquibase-maven-plugin** how to resolve it from `classpath`.

Beside that, there is some additional tips might be helpful for hassle free portable migration those are as following

1. Always use relative path for each `databaseChangeLog`. Example is mentioned in your **db.changelog-master.xml**
2. Use Logical File Path for each `changeSet`

Here is the example for Logical File Path:

```
<changeSet author="chorkeorg" id="1508234245316-1" logicalFilePath="V0/V0.0/V0.0.00/db.changelog-0.0.00.000.xml">
    <createSequence cacheSize="20" cycle="false"
        incrementBy="1" maxValue="999999999999999999999999999" minValue="10001"
        ordered="false" sequenceName="CK_SQ_AUTHOR" startValue="10181" />
</changeSet>
```

Hope it would be resolve your issues properly.